# Display text line-through automatically

Tags: html, css, line-through

I am working on a site and suddenly some of text shows line-through
i try many properties to remove that but no luck please check and give me solution

link : http://alimamahouse.com/real_estate/
check footer and some headings

[image: attachment of issue]

Comment: The issue appears to be caused by the fact that you are using the google translator inline on that site. It looks as if that service tries to indicate something, at least it explicitly marks those text passages as to be visualized that way. I do not see any information about why that is, but a general hint: the quality of that service is so bad from a linguistic point of view that one should not use it anyway, especially not for a commercial service. It looks extremely amateurish. Why don't you simply remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<s cript src
```

it should be

```
<script src
```

thats causing the error

Comment: Wunderful, saw that, but it did not make click in my head. This typo is auto-fixed by the browser to create an `<s>` element... LOL This simply is the correct answer.

Comment: let me try this also

Comment: Thanks this is the perfect solution for the issue

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:**

```
* {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

Comment: This indeed fixes the issue, surprisingly, but it is unclear why exactly. Also it should be noted that `!important` is something like a sledge hammer method anyway. So this is not a solution to the problem, but more like a crude workaround.

Comment: @MrKaMaL Yes, this does change the visualization, you have apply it to the whole document, so palce it inside a script tag in the pages head section. However as said: this is not really a solution.

Comment: @MrKaMaL Please consider this again: this is _not_ a fix, it is a brute force workaround. The correct answer has been given by JavierGonzalez above.

Comment: Right @MrKaMaL , you better to accept Javier Gonzalez answer , right solution it is.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the container doesn't have a css property: `text-decoration: line-through;` applied. Look what sets it and you are done.

Comment: This is not the case. You easily could have checked that yourself with a few clicks.